# Attach to specific process using IDA + WINDBG in kernel debugging

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, windbg, remote-debugging, ida

I want to debug a specific process on a remote system and the only way i can do that is to use the kernel debugging method. 
It works pretty good with just WINDBG, but i think ida can give me the extra edge i need for a better reversing experience.

So far debugging with windbg was successfull but now when i am using the windbg plugin in ida: [image: Ida issue]

what i am actually experiencing is that i cant get the extra analysis from ida, all i can do is attach only to the  process it self (only one available to attach to). and in the Modules window all i can see is the ntkrpamp.exe, which i assume is the kernel process.

i can use all WINDBG regular commands like !process 0 0, etc.. and can debug normally but nothing shows in the IDA window

I have never debugged dynamically using IDA but i can see it is possible..

could it work aswell in a kernel debugging session?

---

Edit:

I just noticed it is possible to analyze a model if i set a breakpoint with the windbg plugin and when IDA hits that breakpoint, this module is added to the IDA Modules windows.

It would be a lot easier if i could just analyze it without pre-putting a breakpoint on the specific module and waiting for it to hit.

Comment: Maybe better suitable on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/